# Prevent double row in navbar (MaterializeCSS)

Tags: css, navbar, materialize

[image: Double row in navbar materializecss]

I'm wondering if there's a way to adjust the navbar in MaterializeCSS to prevent the double row when the number of elements exceeds the width of the browser. I was thinking about some scrollable navbar like the tabs:

[image]

But I can't find a way to implement it.

Comment: Can you target the specific nav items within the navigation and add `{white-space: nowrap; }` to it?

Comment: Ideally you should be testing your layout and implementing a sidenav when appropriate. Also hard to know without seeing your markup because it looks like this isn't standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking inspiration from `nav-tabs`, which exhibit this behaviour as standard:

**Set `nowrap`, `overflow` and `width` on the link container (UL in this case).**

```
nav ul { 
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Set `display`, and unset the `float` on links (LI in this case).**

```
nav ul li { 
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/qBbJqwe)